# is there any other tool that will create database diagram without the SSMS?

Tags: ssms

I need to create the database diagram for my database. i am looking for the external tool that should create the database diagram. And any changes in the database should also change the database diagram. please help me.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to SO. It sounds like you're looking for help with a software tool, so maybe take a look at superuser.com instead. Also have a look here to learn how to get quick and proper responses to your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt238290.aspx) generates Database diagrams for your database.Once you have SSMS installed, expand the database you would like to see the database diagram for, right-click on the database diagrams node to create a new database diagram. If you add all tables to the diagram, existing relationships are visualized.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/310120/viewing-table-relationships-in-sql-server-management-studio